# Why does my locator(xpath) isn't working?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

While giving this locator

```
driver.get("https://ivtripadmindev.azurewebsites.net/login");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("5";
```

Getting this Exception
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Dvn.png)

My Selenium script can't find the input field I want to enter text into. How can I locate it and send my text? (New to automation)

Comment: use this xpath - `//input[@placeholder="Email"]`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below refactored code where I have modified the XPath expression and applied [Selenium's Implicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) to effectively wait until the page is loaded and element is found :

```
driver.get("https://ivtripadmindev.azurewebsites.net/login");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("5");
```

Imports required:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import java.time.Duration;
```